# Do two hash output of same iteration count from different input always different?

Tags: database, hash, unique-constraint, sha

I think I believe that a hash output of same iteration count of a same input always yields same.

Let's say two different inputs.

```
static byte[] hash(byte[] bytes, final int count)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        bytes = digest.digest(bytes);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

With two different input, will two outputs with same count always different?

```
byte[] john = digest("john".getBytes(), 1024);
byte[] jane = digest("jane".getBytes(), 1024);
```

I'm planning to define my database's username column as `BINARY(32)` and I wonder whether I should set the column UNIQUE or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All hashes obviously collide eventually, for input of length greater than the size of the digest. Moreover, few attempt to guarantee lack-of-collisions even for input that is close to the size of the digest

How *often* that happens - under typical, pedantic, or similar inputs - is a result of the quality of the hash.

(for example, a CRC is guaranteed to have distinct hashes for input that changes by a single bit - but secure hashes can't offer that)